# Node.js RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded I dont get where my program get stuck in the loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, solidity

Hello everyone I'm working on my udemy course and i have an issue when i compile with node.js  solidity file with my compiler using windows terminal machine... this is the error I get:

[compiler error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhwTg.png)

and to be clear ill show my solidity code and JavaScript so you guys have better view and would be nice if you can just explain me more what im doing wrong... sorry i may dont give as much info but i hope u guys do understand my problem.

[solidity and JavaScript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7DCC.png)

compile.js file:

```
const path = require('path');

// fs = file system module
const fs = require('fs');

const solc = require('solc');

// give a path to a compiler the file you want to compile:
// "__dirname" means it will start the path from the files folder root in this project root folder is "Inbox"

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf8');

console.log(solc.compile(source, 1));
```

and solidity.sol file

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Inbox{

    string public message;

    constructor(string initialMessage) public {

            message = initialMessage;
    }

    function setMessage(string newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't include code in images.

Comment: sure just fixed that sorry im new here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a JSON-encoded `options` object into the `compile()` function - not just the source code (that's what your current code is doing).

You can find code example in the `solc` package [readme](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js#example-usage-without-the-import-callback).

Comment: thank you sir I appreciate for you answer i solved this problem